# I just can't get my valid password test to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to get my valid password test to pass. When I run it it seems that the `password_digest` hash is different. I don't know what to do to get them to match.

I was mostly using the book "Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example" by Michael Hartl and it seems that he gets this to pass.

Additionally, my application code works just as expected. I can create a user and authenticate them in the console so this is only breaking in tests.

I'm fairly new to testing so I may be missing something obvious here.

Thanks for your help!

I am using bcrypt with `has_secure_password` and here's part relavent user spec code:

```
describe User do

  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

    describe "with a valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with an invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate('invalid') }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save  { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify which spec is failing?

Comment: Turns out my test is trying to create @user over and over again and it's failing.

Comment: Hi yes, Sorry I should have mentioned that. `it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }` This bit is the part that's failing. I just figured out though that my @user is being created every time. Currently trying to figure out how to clear my database before the tests run.

Comment: https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `before { @user.save }`. You may not have realized it, but `before` defaults to `before(:each)`, which means this code runs before each example in the group. You probably expected it to default to `before(:all)`, which runs only once, before all examples in the group.

As you mentioned, you aren't clearing the database after each test. Therefore, before each test, you are calling `@user.save`. This silently fails validation by returning `false`, because you are trying to create another user with the same email address. It's better to use `#save!` so validation exceptions are thrown, making problems like this more obvious.

To summarize:

- Explicitly use `before(:all)` or `before(:each)`
- Use `#save!` instead of `#save`
- Clear the database between each test (try out [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner))

Comment: You are exactly right. I ended up using the database cleaner gem and installed it. It works like a charm now. Thanks for your response!